# Launcher ERROR when submitting hue-generated oozie script

Tags: python, pyspark, oozie, hue

I have a problem running pyspark script through oozie, using hue. I can run the same code included in a script through a notebook or with spark-submit without error, leading me to suspect that something in my oozie workflow is misconfigured. The spark action part of generated for my workflow xml is:

```
<action name="spark-51d9">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <master>yarn</master>
        <mode>cluster</mode>
        <name>MySpark</name>
        <jar>myapp.py</jar>
        <file>/path/to/local/spark/hue-oozie-1511868018.89/lib/MyScript.py#MyScript.py</file>
    </spark>
    <ok to="hive2-07c2"/>
    <error to="Kill"/>
</action>
```

The only message I find in my logs is:

Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class `[org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], exit code [1]`

This is what I have tried so far without solving the problem:
I have tried running it both in yarn client and cluster modes. I have also both tried using paths to a separate directory, and to the hue-generated oozie workflow directory's lib directory in which I have my script. I think that it can find the script, because if I specify another directory I get a message that it is not found. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The way this works for me is:

First you create an sh file that will run your python script.

The file should have the sumbit command:

```
....spark-submit
```

then all the flags you need:

```
--master yarn-cluster......--conf executer-cores 3 .......conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=jar1.jar:jar2.jar --driver-class-path jar1.jar:jar2.jar:jar3.jar
```

and at the end:

```
..... my_pyspark_script.py
```

Then you create a workflow and you choose the shell option and add your sh file as the "shell command" **and** in "files"

From here it's a bit of work to make sure everything is connected properly.
For example I had to add "export" in my sh file so that my "spark/conf" will be properly added.

Comment: Indeed, a shell would work to get the job done. However, I need to use a spark action for maintainability, reproducibility and ease of debugging, so in my case it is not an option.

Comment: Ok, but just so you know, I work with spark in real time production using hundreds of workflows and coordinators and have no problems with maintainability, reproducibility or debugging..

Comment: Thanks, that is really good to know. However, in my specific case I need to do it via spark-action.